# Increase limit of 5000 staged Git changes in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have ~6000 stages changes in my Git project, and Visual Studio Code is showing only the first 5000 with a warning message:

> The git repository has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled

Is there a setting in Visual Studio Code to increase this limit from 5000 to 10000?

(Yes, I actually have ~6000 changed files. It's not an error.)

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41699

Comment: Suggestion: use git from the command line. This gives you all sorts of options to filter long lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [increased limit for Git changes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_61.md#increased-the-limit-for-the-number-of-changed-files-that-the-git-extension-can-show) in VS Code v1.61.

> ##### Increased the limit for the number of changed files that the Git extension can show
>
> Prior to this release, the Git extension had a hard-coded limit of
> 5000 changes that it could show in the Source Control view. The limit
> was to prevent the user from having to wait for too long while we
> processed all the changes reported by Git. We've now increased this
> limit to 10,000 changes, and added a new `git.statusLimit` setting to
> allow users to customize the limit (per repository if desired). This
> setting can also be set to 0 to disable the limit completely, but be
> aware this could cause updates to take a very long time if there are
> lots of changes.
>
> Additionally, we've added the following warning indicator on the input
> box when the limit has been exceeded.

[image: Git change limit warning]

Answer (score 1):

The 5000 limit seems to be hard coded in Visual Studio Code. See [`git.ts/getStatus()`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/159bc687cac56b2c3246ed66b2a13a419ba6b89f/extensions/git/src/git.ts#L1721):

```
getStatus(limit = 5000): Promise<{ status: IFileStatus[]; didHitLimit: boolean; }> {
```

which is invoked from [`updateModelState()`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1ea677191996f1b9c0b0b1f06551863ac12951ba/extensions/git/src/repository.ts#L1489) without an argument, so the default `5000` is used:

```
const { status, didHitLimit } = await this.repository.getStatus();
```